# How can I resize a picturebox proportionally when the form size changes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an image that I want to stay in the same place and size in the form. Anchoring to all sides causes the image to massively expand disproportionately to the form. If I don't dock it at all, the image is in the wrong place and the wrong size. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition, and I'm using a .NET framework.

I've tried anchoring it to different sides, but it always stretches too much, or not at all. Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please describe in detail how you want the image to behave. Show the position of the image in the form and several examples how you want it to change when the form size changes.

Comment: Add a panel to the form  Then add the image to the panel.  The panel will automatically adjust while adding the image directly to the form will not.

Comment: Are you talking about winforms? Use the tags to specify the UI framework you are using.

Comment: The default value of anchored to Left and Top should do exactly what you want... what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following codes will help you.
I had written them for the ResizeEnd event for form1

```
    double Width1 = 1007, Height1 = 725; //The initial size of the form
    private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Width > Width1)
            pictureBox1.Width = 200 + Convert.ToInt32((this.Width - Width1) / 2);
        else
            pictureBox1.Width = 200; //picture Box first Width


        if (this.Height > Height1)
            pictureBox1.Height = 173 + Convert.ToInt32((this.Height - Height1) / 2);
        else
            pictureBox1.Height = 173; //picture Box first Height
    }
```

It is better to define for event Resize as well